# XCode: What do I have to type into the Terminal, in order to change the copyright notice in code templates?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2, xcode4.5, xcode4.3

When I create an XCode project, there is a copyright notice commented out. I know that there is an special terminal command for editing this. Anyone knows it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXCustomTemplateMacroDefinitions '{ORGANIZATIONNAME = "My Company"; }'
```

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXCustomTemplateMacroDefinitions '{"ORGANIZATIONNAME"="stackoverflow";}'
```

or just add a company name to your card in Address Book.

Comment: In case changing your address book card is not working for you, ensure that the system knows that the card is indeed yours. You can do that from Card menu - option "Make My Card"